# How to get dataset attribute of dragged div box?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to get the dataset-attributes "data-price" with two decimalnumbers of dragged div boxes via Javascript to sum them up.

Here my div box:

```
    <div name="qty" id="black" data-price="21.1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

I tried to do it with this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.querySelectorAll("se > div");
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].dataset.price))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].dataset.price);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    }
     </script>
```

but it only counts the data-prices of the non-dragged boxes.

```
      <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
      </script>
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really add the whole HTML code for us to see how you have set the elements with form/name/attributes. I wrote a simple example based on your code and it works just fine for me and it calculates only the elements that are dropped to the `target` element. Also for decimal numbers, use `parseFloat` and not `parseInt`:

```js
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".target > div");
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].dataset.price))
            tot += parseFloat(arr[i].dataset.price);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = tot;
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    
    findTotal();
}

document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() { window.location.reload(); }
```

```css
#black {
background-color: black;
color:white;
}

#red {
background-color: red;
}

#yellow {
background-color: yellow;
}

#green {
background-color: green;
color:white;
}

.qty {
width:50px;
height:50px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}


.target {

height:100px;
border:1px solid grey;

}
```

```html
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<hr>

<form>
<div class="qty" id="black" data-price="21.1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">21.1</div>
<div class="qty" id="red" data-price="16.5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">16.5</div>
<div class="qty" id="yellow" data-price="7.8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">7.8</div>
<div class="qty" id="green" data-price="3.5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">3.5</div>


<h3>Drop items here</h3>
<div class="target" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<h3>Total: </h3>
<div id="total"></div>

</form>
```

My example can also be found here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/jsdd/

Comment: Thank you :D this is exactly what I wanted :))

Comment: This helped me out a lot. Thank you